# jQuery functionality not working on Chrome and IE 8

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, google-chrome

I am a beginner in jQuery.I am working on fixing a bug that I see on my website. I have a ajax call that is executed if you check/uncheck the checkbox in the cart. 
So if I uncheck something in my cart it gets save automatically . This is working in FF but not in Chrome or IE . Any suggestions as to what could be the problem ?

```
function toggleDisplay(id,boutiqueid){
  obj = $('#'+id);
  chk = obj.find('input[name='+id+']');
  if(chk.is(':checked')){
    $.ajax({
      url:'MyRecentPurchaseProcess.jsp?action=add&boutiqueId='+boutiqueid+'&shipment='‌​+id,
      success: function(data) {
        eval(data);
        if(outcome.result=='true'){
          obj = $('#'+id);
          obj.find('.blanket_fold').attr('class','blanket_unfold')
          obj.find('.prod').attr('class','prod_under');
        }
      }
    });
  } // inserted by editor
  else{
    $.ajax({
      url:'MyRecentPurchaseProcess.jsp?action=delete&boutiqueId='+boutiqueid+'&shipmen‌​t='+id,
      success: function(data) {
        eval(data);
        if(funcResult.result == 'true'){
          obj = $('#'+id);
          obj.find('.blanket_unfold').attr('class','blanket_fold')
          obj.find('.prod_under').attr('class','prod');
          chk = obj.find('input[name='+id+']');
          chk.attr('checked',false);
        }
      }
    });
  } // inserted by editor
} // inserted by editor
```

Comment: Could you post your code? You've got a much better chance of getting a solution to your problem if you show what you've got so far.

Comment: Show us your code please. Without code my only guess is that your event listener setup is wrong (onchange/onchecked/onclick?)

Comment: function toggleDisplay(id,boutiqueid){
   obj = $('#'+id);
   chk = obj.find('input[name='+id+']');
   if(chk.is(':checked')){
    $.ajax({
    url:'MyRecentPurchaseProcess.jsp?action=add&boutiqueId='+boutiqueid+'&shipment='+id,
     success: function(data) {
         eval(data);
       if(outcome.result=='true'){
         obj = $('#'+id);
        obj.find('.blanket_fold').attr('class','blanket_unfold')
        obj.find('.prod').attr('class','prod_under');
       }
       }

     });

Comment: function toggleDisplay(id,boutiqueid){

   obj = $('#'+id);

   chk = obj.find('input[name='+id+']');

   

   if(chk.is(':checked')){

    $.ajax({

       url:'MyRecentPurchaseProcess.jsp?action=add&boutiqueId='+boutiqueid+'&shipment='+id,

       success: function(data) {

         eval(data);

       if(outcome.result=='true'){

         obj = $('#'+id);

        obj.find('.blanket_fold').attr('class','blanket_unfold')

        obj.find('.prod').attr('class','prod_under');

       }

       }

     });

Comment: This is the else part of the code

Comment: else{

    $.ajax({

       url:'MyRecentPurchaseProcess.jsp?action=delete&boutiqueId='+boutiqueid+'&shipment='+id,

       success: function(data) {

         eval(data);

       if(funcResult.result == 'true'){

        obj = $('#'+id);

        obj.find('.blanket_unfold').attr('class','blanket_fold')

        obj.find('.prod_under').attr('class','prod');

        chk = obj.find('input[name='+id+']');    

        chk.attr('checked',false);

       }

       }

     });

Comment: I edited your question to include the code with formatting, it will appear after being accepted by a reviewer.

Comment: In the future Jassi, when someone asks to see the code, edit it into your original question.  It's very hard to read when you put it in comments like that.

Comment: I am sorry for not formatting the code . I will be careful next time I post a question.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

IE is strict regarding element ids, look for duplicate ids of the element. FF usually neglects them and works but IE don't.

Answer (score 0):

Please include the code part where you call this function (setting up the event handler), it's hard to find the problem without that. You have some strange selectors but they might be correct, depending on your HTML.

*Note that since jQuery 1.6, using [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) is recommended instead of `attr()` when editing properties like `checked`.*